# Передача дополнительного поля с input

Tags: php, javascript

У меня есть форма, содержащая  несколько полей `input`. Я собираю значения из БД и вставляю их в эти `input`. Далее по кнопке `submit`, методом POST я их обрабатываю. Мне нужно знать в какое именно поле input я соответственно вставил  строчку из БД, то есть необходимо помимо `value` в `input`, так же сохранять `id` этого `value` из БД. Можно ли  невидимо для пользователя передавать этот `id` вместе с `value`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1:

```
<input type="text" name="<?=value_name;?>" value="<?=value;?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="<?=value_id;?>" value="<?=id;?>" />

output:
$_POST['value_name'] = value;
$_POST['value_id'] = id;
```

2:

```
<input type="text" name="some_group[value]" value="<?=value;?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="some_group[id]" value="<?=id;?>" />

output:
$_POST['some_group'] = array(
    'value' => value, 
    'id' => id,
);
```